# REGEX parsing commands from latex lines - Python

Tags: python, regex, latex, lilypond

I'm trying to parse and remove any `\command` (`\textit`, etc...) from each line loaded (from .tex file or other commands from lilypond files as `[\clef, \key, \time]`).

How could I do that?

### What I've tried

```
import re
f = open('example.tex')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

pattern = '^\\*([a-z]|[0-9])' # this is the wrong regex!!
clean = []
for line in lines:
    remove = re.match(pattern, line)
    if remove:
        clean.append(remove.group())

print(clean)
```

### Example

Input

```
#!/usr/bin/latex

\item More things
\subitem Anything
```

Expected output

```
More things
Anything
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple regex substitution using [this pattern](http://regex101.com/r/yV1gQ5) `^\\[^\s]*`:

*Sample code in python:*

```
import re
p = re.compile(r"^\\[^\s]*", re.MULTILINE)

str = '''
\item More things
\subitem Anything
'''

subst = ""

print re.sub(p, subst, str)
```

*The result would be:*

```
More things
Anything
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
'\\\w+\s'
```

It searches for the backslash, then for one or more characters, and a space.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. I also tried using with '^\\\w+\s' but didn't work as well.